# scrape span using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, django, beautifulsoup, headless-browser

I was trying to scrape "span" tag using BeautifulSoup. 
here's my code..

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="someurl"
res=urllib.urlopen(url)
html=res.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
soup.findAll("span")
```

But when I do so, for some specific web pages. it does n't list all the spans.
It just shows limited no. of spans.
but when I do

```
soup.prettify()
```

It contains all the spans..
What might be the reason? Am I missing out on something?
Also some answers I found were to use headless browsers like "htmlunit". but I am not sure what they exactly are? Can I integrate them into my django project?

soup.prettify gives
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhTzDujWhPVTzdIS2VWd1pZcHM/view?usp=sharing

expected output of soup.findAll("span")

```
list of all the spans
```

output im getting

```
[<span class="ssc-ftpl ssc_ga_tag" data-gaa="Opened" data-gac="Footer" data-gal="Responsible Gambling" tabindex="0"> Responsible Gambling</span>, <span class="ssc-ftpl ssc_ga_tag" data-gaa="Opened" data-gac="Footer" data-gal="About Betfair" tabindex="0"> About Betfair</span>, <span class="ssc-ftpl ssc-ftls " tabindex="0">English - UK</span>, <span class="ssc-ftpl" tabindex="0">\xa9 \xae</span>]
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide input, expected output and real output?

Comment: Do a diff between the output of `print(soup)` and `print(soup.prettify())`.  Is there any difference?

Comment: updated with expected output and output im getting

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out the soulution.. the problem was the default "html.parser", which was not able to handle.
Use "html5lib" instead for parsing. and get the desired results.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
soup.findAll("span")
```

html5lib parser parses the page exactly the way a browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to scrape a different page, but I didn't have a problem scraping that site.  Here is my code:

```
url='https://www.betfair.com/sport/football'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

test = soup.find_all('span')
for span in test:
    print(span)
```

This produced a large list of spans including the lines/scores which is what I figured you are interested in:

```
<span class="ssc-lkh"></span>
<span>Join Now</span>
<span class="new flag-en"></span>
<span class="new flag-en"></span>
<span class="sportIcon-6423"></span>
<span class="sportName">American Football</span>
<span class="sportIcon-3988"></span>
<span class="sportName">Athletics</span>
<span class="sportIcon-61420"></span>
.....
```

**Updated in response to the comment below**

Here is some revised code to show that my code does indeed pull in the `span`s you need.

```
url='https://www.betfair.com/sport/football'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

test = soup.find_all('span',attrs={"class":"away-team-name"}) 
for span in test:
    print("away team" + span.text)
```

Produces:

```
away team
Marseille

away team
Lazio

away team
Academica

away team
Canada (W)

away team
Arnett Gardens FC

away team
UWI FC
....
```

Comment: yea. your one will also not be listing all the spans. check out for span containing the name of team of any ongoing or in-play match.. like  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhTzDujWhPVekN6UW9CUzd0eWc/view?usp=sharing this one

Comment: @sidharthkumar  Did you try my code?  When I run it it gets those `span`s.  Please see my updated code where I explicitly get the `span` you say you can't get.

Comment: i did same(almost).. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhTzDujWhPVNGE4Sk9xTW10UFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks for help. used html5lib as the parser and got the output